# Why does declaration of function with int return type is not compulsory in C?

Tags: c, function, forward-declaration, function-declaration

```
int main ()
{
hello();

return 0;
}

int hello()
{

printf("\n hello world");

return 0;
}
```

as per C rule every function which is defined below the `main()` must be declared above `main()`  but why it's exception for function which has `int` as return type?
if you change return type of `hello()`  to anything else (void, char * etc)
it will throw error for declaration .  Why there is no error or warning for `int`  return type ?

Comment: Your question is unclear, add the code you are trying to describe, instead of describing it. Also add the actual error you get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are prototypes required for all functions in C89, C90 or C99?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434763/are-prototypes-required-for-all-functions-in-c89-c90-or-c99)

Comment: [Is it portable to define and declare the function after calling it in main in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8502817/995714)

Answer (score 5):

This is an old feature of C, which is now officially unsupported.

In earlier days (*before C99, if I'm not wrong*), in case of a missing return type for a function, or in case a function was missing a forward declaration, the function was **assumed** to return an `int` and accept any number of arguments. Your actual definition of the function also matches that *assumption*, so the linker also does not complain.

Your compiler still supports that old feature (*mainly due to maintain the backward compatibility to the programs written using the older standards*), hence you are successfully compiling and linking the program.

FYI, in the latest C standard, `C11`, it is officially mentioned

> - remove implicit function declaration

so, as per the strict checking, **it is compulsory** to forward declare a function (or, define before it's usage, so that compiler does not have to assume anything).

Answer (score 0):

Due to its history of development and evolution, C has kept things that would have been deprecated in other languages. This is because there is a lot of older C code that would break if C compilers did not maintain backward compatibility.

The idea is that new C code should use new styles and conventions. However C compilers try their best to maintain compatibility with older source style and conventions.

Due to the reluctance of C compiler vendors to break existing, older source code, you will see C source code that compiles yet seems to break the rules of the newer C standards.

Working with older source myself, when I use Visual Studio 2015 the number of warnings are incredible because the same issues are repeatedly marked. The result is for this large body of code there are certain warnings I turn off.

The function declaration thing you mention is just one. There is also the new security types of string functions and I/O functions versus the old style that did not have the additional length arguments.

Answer (score 0):

There was a convention in C that functions declared without return type have return type int by default.
Also the default type specifier of variables also was int. For example Borland C++ Builder 5.0 supported such declaration

```
const VALUE = 10;
```

Comment: I haven't declared function(`hello()`) at all with or without return type .

Answer (score 0):

Ever since C99, a declaration has been required in advance of use; once an implementation issues a diagnostic for a failure to include such a declaration, it may continue processing the source file or not as it sees fit.

In the earlier days of C, before `void` was added to the language, `int` was by far the most common return type.  Argument types would be inferred at each call site, so the compiler didn't need to know anything about any function other than its return type.  Further, text editors that could handle files larger than 32K were considered a luxury, and being able to skip the preprocessor could shave multiple seconds off compilation times.  Put those facts together, and being able to omit the declarations for the majority of functions increased the amount of useful code that could be included within each source file.